# Angular Library build with --base-href

Tags: maven, npm, angular8, npm-scripts, angular-library

I have couple of custom Angular libraries, which will be used in angular runnable application. where this runnable application is build using `ng build --deploy-url="dist/" --base-href="appContextPath"`, and copied in to war file using maven plugins.

when i run the application using http://localhost:8080/appContextPath, assets which are part of runnable application are loading but the library assets are not loading.

My observation:

1) Application assets loading url in developer tools:

http://localhost:8080/appContextPath/assets/images/search.png <---- this gets loaded

2) Library assets loading url in developer tools:

http://localhost:8080/assets/images/xyz.png <---- gives as 404, due to `base-href` is not appended.

Answer (score 0):

From [angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#html5-urls-and-the--base-href):

```
The <base href> path should end with a "/", as browsers ignore characters in the path 
that follow the right-most "/".
```

In your case, try  `--base-href="/appContextPath/"`